# SQL CASE with conversion statements

Tags: sql, case

I need to do a select that convert a value to int and set a number in another column.

```
SELECT
    * ,
    (CASE WHEN City = 'London' THEN '2' ELSE '1' END) AS Status 
FROM
    customers
```

The problem is that I want to convert 2 in a INT:

```
SELECT
    * ,
    (CASE WHEN City = 'London' THEN CAST(City AS INT) '2' ELSE '1' END) AS Status 
FROM
    customers
```

It seems that it accept only one operation in THEN?

Comment: `CAST(City as int)` in that context is the same as `CAST('London' as int)` - how can you expect that to work? Also (unrelated): `'1'` is a string, `1` is a number

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: If you want Status to be an int, it should be `(CASE WHEN City='London' then 2 ELSE 1 END) as Status`, so without the quotes around the numbers.

Comment: @DaVe . . . A `case` expression is a *scalar* expression in SQL, meaning that it returns only one value.  Some databases allow that one value to be a tuple, but it is still only one value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
 SELECT  * ,
(CASE WHEN City = 'London' THEN CAST('2' AS INT) ELSE CAST('1' AS INT) END) AS Status 
FROM
customers
```

or

```
 SELECT  * ,
(CASE WHEN City = 'London' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS Status 
FROM
customers
```

For your conversion of city name into `numeric`, it seems unrealistic you can never convert a city name into integer by anyhow in any world.